# Programming with GLFW and Glew on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, opengl, glfw, glew

I have the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import </usr/local/Cellar/glew/1.12.0/include/GL/glew.h>
#import </usr/local/Cellar/glfw2/2.7.9/include/GL/glfw.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
     @autoreleasepool
     {
         if(!glfwInit())
         {
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors when compiling: glew.h User-defined Issue Gltypes.h included before glew.h Modules Issue Declaration of PFNGLCOPYTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC must be imported from module 'OpenGL.GL3' before it is required

There are another 19 errors that are all semantic errors. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out I didn't properly compile the library files.